# Where does the default `make` behavior come from?

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I'm pretty new to Makefiles; thus, I encountered a question for which I can't come up with a good google search to help answer.

I am running a virtual OS which has a distro of fedora setup by someone else.  If I construct my own Makefile in a directory, I can setup my `.c` files to compile however I like.  Yet, if I simply run `make test`, whereby in my directory exists `test.c`, I will get the following : `clang -ggdb3 -std=c99 -Wall -Werror  test.c -lcs50 -lm -o test`.

My question following this observation was where does this default, seemingly universal, `make` behavior come from?  In other words, where does this Makefile, if it is one, sit on my file system?

Comment: It's hard-wired into `make`, if I'm not terribly mistaken. This utility has a number of default rules for compiling various source types, of which the most popular one is, of course, the compilation of C (and eventually C++) programs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`make` has [several predefined implicit rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules).  Two of which are:

***Compiling C programs***
*n.o is made automatically from n.c with a recipe of the form ‘$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c’.*

***Linking a single object file***
*n is made automatically from n.o by running the linker (usually called ld) via the C compiler. The precise recipe used is ‘$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) n.o $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS)’.*

Note, `make` is smart enough to effectively concatenate the above two into one rule when it makes sense:

*... could be done by using the ‘.o’ object files as intermediates, but it is faster to do the compiling and linking in one step, so that's how it's done.*

You can dump the predefined rules with `make -pn`.  e.g.:

```
$ make -pn -f /dev/null | grep -A3 '^%: %.c$'
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
%: %.c
#  commands to execute (built-in):
    $(LINK.c) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@

$
```

Comment: Thanks for both of the helpful answers @DigitalTrauma and @nos .  The `make -pn` command was very useful to me in finding out where all of this is coming from "by default".  It showed me all the environment vars I was confused about.

Answer (score 2):

This goes for GNU make, which normally is the default `make` implementation on linux.

There's no default Makefile on your file system containing the default rules.
There are however implicit rules built into make that are in effect whether you supply a makefile or not, and what `make` does when invoked
is documented [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Running).

These rules knows e.g. how to build an executable from a .c source file. You can learn about those implicit rules [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Rules),

e.g make has this default rule when building an executable:

> n is made automatically from n.o by running the linker (usually called
>   ld) via the C compiler. The precise recipe used is ‘$(CC) $(LDFLAGS)
>   n.o $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS)’

Meaning if you run `make test` it will try to create an executable `test` from the file test.o, and you can set the respective CC/LDFLAGS/etc. variables that will be used when linking.

And as another implicit rule it can build a .o file from a .c file, so the above will look for `test.o`, and try to rebuild that using the rule:

> n.o is made automatically from n.c with a recipe of the form ‘$(CC)
>   $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c’.

I.e. the implicit rules when running `make test` will first compile test.c and then link test.o using the compiler you specify with the CC envirnment variable(or the default compiler `cc`) and the various compiler/linker flags if you set then as environment variables.

.